# I am getting the error in Python 3.6 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am getting the error in Python 3.6 TypeError:

> '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

I am trying to take data from another Python program and use it to show when flexing or not but I do not know the syntax for this. My code is pasted below.

I just need to get the 8 bit unsigned integer to be compared to the data being taken in.

```
import pyglet
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import socket
import threading
import sys
import os
import math

#Un-comment this if using OS-X.
#os.system('defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO')

WindowSize = 5000
SampleRate = 1000.0
VoltsPerBit = 2.5/256

#Define global variables
Fs = 1000
FlexWindowSize = 0.25
data = []
displayData = [-2 for i in range(WindowSize)]
flexing = False

# This reads from a socket.
def data_listener():
  global data
  UDP_PORT = 9000
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
  sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  while True:
    newdata, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    data.extend(list(newdata))

#Handle command line arguments to get IP address
if (len(sys.argv) == 2):
    try:
        UDP_IP = sys.argv[1]
        socket.inet_aton(UDP_IP)
    except:
        sys.exit('Invalid IP address, Try again')
else:
    sys.exit('EMG_Acquire <Target IP Address>')

#Connect the UDP_Port
UDP_PORT = 9000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

print('Connected to ', str(UDP_IP))
print("Listening for incoming messages...")
print('Close Window to exit')

#Start a new thread to listen for data over UDP
thread = threading.Thread(target=data_listener)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

#Load and place image resources
pyglet.resource.path = ['./resources']
pyglet.resource.reindex()
ForeArm_image = pyglet.resource.image("forearm.png")
Bicep_image = pyglet.resource.image("Bicep.png")
ForeArm_image.anchor_x = 7
ForeArm_image.anchor_y = ForeArm_image.height-150
Bicep_image.anchor_x = Bicep_image.width/2
Bicep_image.anchor_y = Bicep_image.height/2

#Define the moving ForeArm class
class ForeArm(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ForeArm,self).__init__(img=ForeArm_image,*args, **kwargs) 
    self.rotate_speed = 100.0
    self.rotation_upper_limit = -10
    self.rotation_lower_limit = -100
    self.rotation = self.rotation_upper_limit
    self.key_handler = pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler()

  def update(self, dt):
    if flexing:
      if not ((self.rotation-self.rotate_speed*dt) <=   self.rotation_lower_limit):
        self.rotation -= self.rotate_speed*dt
      else:
        self.rotation = self.rotation_lower_limit
    else:
      if not((self.rotation+self.rotate_speed*dt) >= self.rotation_upper_limit):
        self.rotation += self.rotate_speed*dt
      else:
        self.rotation = self.rotation_upper_limit

#Setup the main window
main_window = pyglet.window.Window(1000,600)
main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
background = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(0)
foreground = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(1)
bicep = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=Bicep_image,x=350,y=150,batch=main_batch,group=background)
forearm = ForeArm(x=510, y=115,batch=main_batch,group=foreground)
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
main_window.push_handlers(forearm)
main_window.push_handlers(forearm.key_handler)


def update(dt):
  global displayData, data, flexing

  newData = list(data)

  data = []
  newDisplay = list(displayData[len(newData):len(displayData)] + newData)
  displayData = list(newDisplay)

  #Put your flex algorithm code here!
  #If flexing is detected, set the 'flexing' variable to True.
  #Otherwise, set it to False. 
  #############################
  #ALL OF YOUR CODE SHOULD GO BELOW HERE

  if displayData > 20:
    flexing = True
  else: 
    flexing = False

  #ALL OF YOUR CODE SHOULD GO ABOVE HERE
  forearm.update(dt)

@main_window.event
def on_draw():
    main_window.clear()
    main_batch.draw()

   pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/120.0)
   pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Please post your *minimal* code and the full error message.

Comment: You have `displayData = list()` then `displayData > 20`, you can't compare those two, as the error message states

Comment: But how do I take the data from displayData and make it so I can compare it to an 8 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: What do you actually want to compare? The first element? If *any* elements are larger? If the array is has more than 20 things?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are already instantiating `newDisplay` as a list, so there is no need to do `displayData = list(newDisplay)`. You can just do `displayData = newDisplay`.

Secondly, when you try to evaluate `displayData > 5`, you are comparing a list to an integer. This is like asking, "is this list greater than 5?". That doesn't make logical sense.

A much more common paradigm is to ask if a list's *length* is greater than some number. Are you trying to say, "If the length of the `displayData` list is greater than 20, do something" ? If so, use `if len(displayData) > 5`.

However, you have some bigger logical issues in these lines of your code:

```
newDisplay = list(displayData[len(newData):len(displayData)] + newData)
displayData = list(newDisplay)
```

You are trying to use `displayData` within your `newDisplay` definition, but `displayData` doesn't exist yet at that point in your code.

As another person mentioned, we can help you more effectively if you post just enough code to convey your problem, along with the full error message.